# How do I "alias" the execution of a .jar file as a global command?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have a Java executable file, `swagger-codegen-cli.jar`, that I'd like to be able to execute globally from the console like I would with an `.exe` in my environment PATH.

Currently if I want to execute it, I have to type `java -jar C:\Users\Jacob\swagger-codegen-cli.jar`.

How can I "alias" (what's the proper term?) this command globally as something succinct, like `swagger-codegen`? So something like this:

`java -jar C:\Users\Jacob\swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i http://localhost/swagger/docs/v1`

becomes this:

`swagger-codegen generate -i http://localhost/swagger/docs/v1`

Comment: Write a batch file and put it into your path. See [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a batch file with the following:

```
java -jar C:\Users\Jacob\swagger-codegen-cli.jar %*
```

The `%*` portion tells the batch script to pass all of the parameters it receives to the new command.

If there are no other executables in the same directory as the `.jar` file, you can safely save the batch file there as `swagger-codegen.bat` and then add it to your `PATH` variable.

If there are other executables in the same directory, make sure they don't conflict with any other commands that might be reachable through your `PATH` variable.

Comment: This did the trick, though I had to put my path in quotes even though it has no spaces or odd characters. `java -jar C:\Users\Jacob\executables\swagger-codegen-cli.jar` gave me the `Unable to access jarfile` error, but `java -jar "C:\Users\Jacob\executables\swagger-codegen-cli.jar"` worked just fine

Answer (score 2):

The [`DOSKEY`](https://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) command can create an alias in `cmd`:

```
doskey swagger-codegen=java -jar C:\Users\Jacob\swagger-codegen-cli.jar
```

If you need this to be defined whenever `cmd` starts, you can define it in an [initialisation file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17405182/5164855).

Comment: Does this support command arguments? i.e. `swagger-codegen -i someArg`

Comment: @JacobStamm Yes. Add `$*` to the end of the `doskey` command.

Comment: @JacobStamm - The substitution is made in-line, so any extra parameters remain on the command line and are passed to the expanded command. You can add `$*`, but it's not really needed unless you wand to add extra parameters to the end of the run string.